# Is it possible to disable symlinks when mounting a partition?

Tags: linux, mount, symlink, usb-drive

I have an embedded system development setup which is supposed to restrict users from accessing any system folders.

On a USB stick I created a symlink to "/" (root folder) and when I click on it in the file browser it will bring the file manager to root directory.

Is there any option to give to mount command to disable symlinks, as in not to follow the symlink?

If so, is it the same for all filesystems? Mainly fat32, NTFS and EXT3/4?

Comment: FreeBSD actually has a mount option that does this (`nosymfollow`). It’s honestly not very useful though except as extra insurance against other security measures failing.

Answer (score 12):

Your symlink disabling is utterly meaningless; if a user *can* access `/`, then there's thousands of ways of *reverse path traversal* attacks on your system. Simple example: if they have access to a "open file" dialog, they can just type in `/etc/passwd`, and get that; your average file explorer has a shortcut for allowing people to directly enter paths and so on. If they can open HTML pages, that page can have an `<frameset><frame src="file:///" /></frameset>`, or link: `<a href="../../../../../../../">foo</a>`, and show the / directory in their browser. The list goes on, and the approach you're taking, plugging one single hole after the other, is what typically leads to vulnerabilities where every person who's been into computer security in the early 2000s would say "oh, what a 1990s problem!".

Solutions are straightforward: make it *impossible* for  the software the users interact with to even see the real system /. In the olden day you would have done that with a `chroot` call; these days, Linux kernel namespaces allow far better and more extensive isolation (including things like not being able to access sockets, network, PIDs, users…).

One off-the-shelf method of deploying user software that can access graphical interfaces, but none of the files on the host system is `bwrap` ("Bubblewrap"), but you'll probably want to use that simply by building a *flatpak* package containing your software, which you don't grant file access privileges.

Comment: Thanks for your detailed answer. Indeed my approach is naive ... it is harder than I initially thought

Comment: it's not. I have made a direct recommendation how to easily solve this.